# Blank black screen after removing MainStoryboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, appdelegate

I wanted to get rid of the storyboard and make everything in nib files. So I removed the main story board and coded the launch routine in the app delegate. I also deleted the storyboard name in the summary section of the app target so the complier won't complain. However, now nothing is shown when the app is launch, only a black blank screen. Is there away to fix this without creating a new non-storyboard project?

Here is the code in my app delegate..

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    MasterViewController *mainController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [navController pushViewController:mainController animated:YES];

    [self.window addSubview:navController.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your Info.plist to indicate the main nib file and not a storyboard file. You'll need to change both the key (`UIMainStoryboardFile` to `NSMainNibFile`) and the associated value.

Answer (score 0):

When you deleted the main story board you also deleted the StoryBoard Entry Point. To fix this, replace the StoryBoard Entry Point and you should get the desired display.

Thanks,
Rajat

[StoryBoard Entry Point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/We801.png)